# Installing a 32bit printer driver on 64bit Windows Server 2008 - Architecture Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, shared-printers, drivers

When using the Print Server options in Windows Server 2008 on a 64bit machine to install "Additional Drivers" for my HP LaserJet 4200 that is networked to 32bit machines I receive an error regarding trying to install on the incorrect architecture.

I'm not 100% sure why I am receiving this error as I am trying to install it as the x86 driver and not the 64bit.

What are my options to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you [following the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732946.aspx) when installing the driver? As a workaround, you can try installing the driver from a 32-bit client:

1. log on as a domain administrator on a 32-bit client
2. open Windows Explorer and navigate to the `\\server` UNC path
3. click the "view remote printers" button (Windows 7) or double-click the "Printers" icon (Windows XP) to get the list of the printers, open the "Properties" of the printer in question, navigate to the "Share" tab and click "additional drivers".
4. install the drivers for the x86 architecture

Comment: Thanks but neither of these solutions work. I am able to "install" additional drivers from the client machine but when I actually attempt to print I am met with a driver error.

I am using the correct drivers. I believe this may be an issue with the HP Printer Driver itself or some sort of bug.

Answer (score -2):

its due to compatibility problem its not recognizing the x32 over x64 version....install the x64 version hp laserjet 4200 printer drivers it will resolve your issues....get back with the result to make sure you overcome with the problem.

Comment: This doesn't address his issue at all as he needs the 32 bit drivers on his print server so 32 bit clients using said print server can obtain the drivers.